# iPhone Adwhirl 3.2 InMobi integration

Tags: iphone, adwhirl, inmobi

I'm tryting to integrate InMobi 3.6.0 SDK into the adWhirl 3.2 on iPhone. 
The app can't be built because of the following error:

```
- (GenderType)gender;     Error: Expected a type
```

I've tried to use .h and .m files for adwhirl 3.0 InMobiAdapter, but they also return errors.
Help me with this problem, please!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem solved.
Here is the link to the SDK and adapters needs to be replaced: http://developer.inmobi.com/wiki/index.php?title=InMobi_AdWhirl_Adapter_SDK_3.6.0